# Trying to understand dijkstra's algorithm in prolog

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, dijkstra

I'm trying to understand [this](http://colin.barker.pagesperso-orange.fr/lpa/dijkstra.htm) code. The values I need to provide in the predicate **"path"** using the facts is confusing for me, I can't really understand that predicate, can someone provide some examples with the facts **"dist"**?

Comment: In `path/4` you need to provide the two cities as `Vertex0` and `Vertex`...

Comment: path(Vertex0, Vertex, Path, Dist), what about Path and Dist, I don't get it, that's why I would appreciate some examples

Comment: There is a query of example in the program: `?- path(penzance, london, Path, Dist).` `Dist = 304, Path = [penzance, exeter, bristol, london].` So `Dist` is the distance and `Path` is the path...

Comment: Of interest: [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code)  [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Prolog)